# How to get response text when Got package crashes with bad JSON?

Tags: node.js

```
import got from "got";

try {
    await got('https://google.com').json();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    // how do I get response text here?
}
```

Hi. I have an API endpoint that normally returns JSON, but sometimes there's an error and it prints something that breaks the JSON. Got just crashes with `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`. How do I get the actual faulty text here?

Comment: Sounds to me like this is the actual error message. Usually this error would apply if the server returns HTML instead of JSON. Can you check for the actual response that is logged in your network tab?

Comment: @FabianStrathaus this is running on a server

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. You want to log the actual error response sent by the API call, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in got's documentation, [ParseError](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/blob/main/documentation/8-errors.md#parseerror) includes a `response` property, which you can use to retrieve the raw response.

```
import got, { ParseError } from "got";

try {
    await got('https://google.com').json();
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    // how do I get response text here?
    if(e instanceof ParseError)
    {
        console.log(e.response.body);
    }
}
```